# TraCI server "SUMO 0.22.0" reports API version 8. This server is unsupported

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to simulate VANET in OMNeT++ and I have used Veins and SUMO as well in the simulation but I have got this error:

> Error in module (TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) uiascenario.manager
>   (id=5) at event #1, t=0: Model error:  Error in module
>   (TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) uiascenario.manager (id=5) at event #1,
>   t=0: Model error: TraCI server "SUMO 0.22.0" reports API version 8.
>   This server is unsupported..

The strange thing is that it works with Veins example, but it doesn't work with my project while I am using the same map and SUMO configuration files of Veins example.

Comment: pleae report which version of Veins and OMNeT++ you use. SUMO is obviously version 0.22, right?

Comment: also a quickfix would be to downgrade to an earlier version of SUMO, 0.21 or 0.20 should be fine...

Comment: @user4786271 hi sir , i am using omnet++4.6 and i am using sumo 0.22.0 and veins 3.0 ... i tried to use sumo 0.21.0 and sumo 0.23.0 as well but it doesnt work , the strange thing is that the veins example in Veins works fine but with my project it doesnt work !! i appreciate your cooperation

Comment: can you add the error messages you received when using sumo version 0.22 and 0.21... you certainly should not use sumo version 0.22, 0.23 with veins 3. Although I doubt, but the Veins example may have been tailored to work with "any" sumo version, because it is fairly simple. So don't take it as a reference point.

Comment: @user4786271 
Hi sir , i have used SUMO-0.22.0 with veins example and it runs smoothly ..
this is the errors that i got when i use sumo 0.22.0 with my own project

<!> Error in module (TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) uiascenario.manager (id=5) at event #1, t=0: Model error: TraCI server "SUMO 0.22.0" reports API version 8. This server is unsupported..


and this is the error when i use sumo 0.21.0

<!> Error in module (TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) uiascenario.manager (id=5) at event #1, t=0: Model error: TraCI server "SUMO 0.21.0" reports API version 8. This server is unsupported..

Comment: What version of Veins do you use?

Comment: Dear @user4786271
the problem has been solved by replacing the sumo.0.22 by sumo-0.15. i ran my simulation smmothly but now i am getting an error of the following

<!> Error in module (TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) uiascenario.manager (id=5) at event #1, t=0: Model error: Connection to TraCI server lost. Check your server's log. Error message: 10054: Unknown error.

please how can i correct this error !

Comment: I simply don't get why you have so hard time reporting the version of Veins you are using?!? Telling it might solve multiple of the problems you are facing. BB

Comment: the new error says enough: `Check your server's log.` without that info being added to the question, its hard to tell what your problem is!

Comment: just a reminder any unhelpful question leads to `downvotes`,  `very low quality` flags: _This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed._ , which results in account locking

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there is some mismatch between the SUMO version and the Veins version that you use. Since the OP has not reported the version of the tools he uses here I will provide the info from the [Veins changelog](http://veins.car2x.org/download/):

> **Changelog**
>
> New in Veins 4 alpha 2
>
> ```
> requires SUMO 0.22.0
> ```
>
> New in Veins 4 alpha 1
>
> ```
> requires SUMO 0.22.0
> ```
>
> New in Veins 3.0
>
> ```
> requires SUMO 0.21.0
> ```
>
> New in Veins 3 alpha 1
>
> ```
> requires SUMO 0.19.0
> ```
>
> New in Veins 2.2
>
> ```
> updates for SUMO 0.19.0
> ```